# Using Winrar CMD Examing structure

Tags: perl, cmd, winrar

I have a bunch of rar files some of which contain just the file or files and some have A directory structure

i'd like to create a bat file that can extract the rar with the directory as is & if no directory use the rar file name to create a directory & then extract to that off course handling any errors

so this cmd will output a list to a text file

```
C:\Program Files\WinRAR>UnRAR.exe l H:\temp\test.rar >H:\temp\test.txt
```

results in

```
UNRAR 4.20 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2012 Alexander Roshal

Archive H:\temp\Test.rar

 Name             Size   Packed Ratio  Date   Time     Attr      CRC   Meth Ver
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Test.TXT            0        0   0% 20-11-12 18:44  .....A.   00000000 m0b 2.9
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1                0        0   0%
```

for a rar file without a directory structure and

```
UNRAR 4.20 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2012 Alexander Roshal

Archive H:\temp\testDir.rar

 Name             Size   Packed Ratio  Date   Time     Attr      CRC   Meth Ver
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Test.TXT            0        0   0% 20-11-12 18:44  .....A.   00000000 m0b 2.9
 test                0        0   0% 20-11-12 18:45  .D.....   00000000 m0  2.0
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2                0        0   0%
```

with a directory

I could create a perl script that will output this listing to a temp text file read it find / pattern match .D..... test if that directory exists & test if the files exits

then create another bath file to extract the files

But I was wondering if there was a simpler way?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with a batch scrpit like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.rar) do (
  UnRAR.exe l "%%a" | findstr /C:".D....." >nul
  if !errorlevel!==0 (
    echo File %%a contains dirs
    UnRAR.exe x "%%a"
  )
  if !errorlevel!==1 (
    echo File %%a does not contain dirs, extracting in %%~na
    mkdir "%%~na"
    UnRAR.exe x "%%a" "%%~na\"
  )
)
```

This will execute `UnRAR.exe l filename` for every `*.rar` file in current dir, it then checks if it contains the string `.D.....`, and it extract the rar in the current dir if the string is not found, otherwise it will create a directory with the same filename as the archive (but without the extension) and extracts the archive there. Please check if the syntax of UnRAR.exe that i've used is correct.

**EDIT:** this codes loops recursively through subdirectories:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /r "%1" %%a in (*.rar) do (
  UnRAR.exe l "%%a" | findstr /C:".D....." >nul
  if !errorlevel!==0 (
    echo File %%a contains dirs, extracting in "%%~dpa"
    UnRAR.exe x "%%a" "%%~dpa"
  )
  if !errorlevel!==1 (
    echo File %%a does not contain dirs, extracting in %%~dpna
    mkdir "%%~na"
    UnRAR.exe x "%%a" "%%~dpna\"
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanx Thats Grate. I added a line cd /d %1 to take a path as a parameter how would i recurzivly loop through each sub dirs?

Comment: @holly see my updated answer for looping through each sub dir.. thanks